# Как разбить класс активити на части ( на классы)

Tags: android, классы, activity

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно разбить класс `Activity` ( у меня одна `Activity`) на отельные классы, если каждый метод в `Activity` использует `View`. Как можно абстрагироваться от этих `View`?

Answer (score 1):

Вам можно посмотреть в сторону ["Шаблонов проектирования"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), например [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) или [MVP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter).

Comment: в архитектуре Android шаблон MVC и так используется "по умолчанию". Разметка - View, Activity - Controller и отображаемые на разметке данные - Model

Comment: это не мешает прочесть об этом, а потом решить, как всё таки лучше построить архитектуру в данных условиях